# JQuery .slideToggle()

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I'm using slideToggle() in JQuery to display a div.
But this doesn't work.

I made different tests but nothing works...

I have this :

```
<div class="domaine">
<a>1. Compétences Scientifiques Transversales</a>
<br>
<div class="ssdomaine" style="display: none;">
    <a>1.1. Sciences et techniques</a>
    <br>
    <div class="competence" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#">1.1.1. Génie thermique et thermodynamique</a>
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is just a single "domaine" containing a single "ssdomaine" containing a single "competence"

But I make a request in a database which can send me multiple "domaine" containing multiple "ssdomaine" containint multiple "ssdomaine".

I want to make a .slideToggle() without specifying any id.

My JQuery code is :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ssdomaine').hide();
    $('.competence').hide();
   $('.domaine a').click(function() {
      $(this).next('.ssdomaine').slideToggle(1000);
      return false;
   });
   $('.ssdomaine a').click(function() {
          $(this).next('.competence').slideToggle(1000);
          return false;
    });
 });
</script>
```

And I tried the same in this link : 
http://jsfiddle.net/6GRJr/168/

And it's working, but it is on only one occurence of domaine, ssdomaine and competence.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the `height`, look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6GRJr/169/

**UPDATE**

The reason why it doesn't show `competence` is because it is hidden when you load the form, and when you do `slideToggle` on `ssdomaine` it makes `ssdomaine` only visible not competence aswell

**UPDATE**

This should do it http://jsfiddle.net/6GRJr/172/

Comment: It is normal, I don't want competence to be visible as well.
Sorry if I didn't explain well, when I click, nothing appears. And I want ssdomaine to appear, and if I click on ssdomaine, I want competence to appear.

Comment: Thanks it solves in part my problem. It's what I want, but with an exception. When I click on a domain, I only want ssdomain include in the domaine to appear. Here, if I have multiple domaine and I click on a domain, every domain let appear ssdomain. Any more idea ?

Comment: Mmhhh this is nearly perfect. This is good for ssdomaine, but when I select a ssdomaine, every ssdomaine of the same domaine let appear their competences.

E.g :

"domaine 1

domaine 2"

I select domaine 1 :

"domaine 1
  ssdomaine1
  ssdomaine2

domaine2"

I select ssdomaine 2 :

"domaine 1
  ssdomaine1
   competence1
   competence2

  ssdomaine2
   competence2.1
   competence2.2

domaine2"

In ths example, I don't wanna have competence2.1 and competence2.2 to appear.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: ("Enters" were not added in this comment sorry, do you understand the example anyways ?)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's slideToggle() is buggy at best. Fortunately there is a new feature in HTML5 that will provide this functionality without JavaScript!

Check out the new HTML5  tag:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp

Answer (score 0):

`.next` only looks at the immediate sibling, adding a selector only checks if that element matches the selector, `.nextAll('.selector')`  is the way to go, but will return a collection of elements, so you may want to limit the collection using `.first()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.ssdomaine').hide();
    $('.competence').hide();
   $('.domaine a').click(function() {
      // next only looks at the immediate sibling, which in you code is a <br />
      //$(this).next('.ssdomaine').slideToggle(1000);


      // this would open all elements
      $(this).nextAll('.ssdomaine').slideToggle(1000);
```

or

```
      // this would open this first instance of .ssdomaine
      $(this).nextAll('.ssdomaine').first().slideToggle(1000);

      return false;
   });
   $('.ssdomaine a').click(function() {
          $(this).next('.competence').slideToggle(1000);
          return false;
    });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot both of you !
I took a bit of the two answers and this became :

http://jsfiddle.net/6GRJr/174/

And it's doing what I want.

Again thank you for your time.

Kiruchi